# Cargo build --verbose --target=i686-linux-android makes target_os NOT android, why?

Tags: rust

If I build my project with

`cargo build --verbose --target=i686-linux-android`

where `build.rs` looks like this

```
fn main() {
    #[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
    {
        panic!("target_os is linux!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
```

I get the panic at `panic!("target_os is linux!!!!!!!!!!!!!");`, but the target is android.

Why?

Comment: Since android is a linux distribution, it's normal that if the target is android, then the target OS is linux, isn't it?

Comment: @BlackBeans true, however [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_os) for `target_os` lists both "linux" and "android" as separate things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `build.rs` script is compiled and run *locally* and thus its `#[cfg(...)]` attributes will reflect the *local* system. If you want to know the operating system that you're ultimately building for, use the `CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS` environment variable.

Others can be seen in [Environment variables Cargo sets for build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-build-scripts) in the Rust Reference.